# Including pdfpages in a revtex document rotates the page

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, revtex

When using pdfpages with revtex, all pages in the original document change from portrait to landscape upon simply including the package via \usepackage{pdfpages}. This is a MWE illustrating the issue:

```latex
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Here is an image:
[image: pdfpages with revtex]

This issue does not occur with \documentclass{article}.

Here is an image:
[image: pdfpages with article class]

Comment: Also occurs with `revtex4-2` on OverLeaf FYI for anyone who knows the solution